# Alinhar botão JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Quero alinhar um único botão ao JPanel, mas não estou conseguindo, esta usando o layout padrão.

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

    private JButton btn;
    private JPanel painel;
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    private JTextArea tArea;

    public Test() {

        btn = new JButton("Sair");
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(72, 35));
        btn.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));

        painel = new JPanel();
        painel.add(btn, FlowLayout.LEFT); //nao funciona

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tArea = new JTextArea());
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.add(painel, "North");
        cp.add(scroll, "Center");

        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btn);

        setSize(400, 280);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Alinhar como, a esquerda?

Comment: Isso mesmo, esqueci de dizer.

Comment: A resposta lhe ajudou? Se sim, você pode marcá-la como aceita, clicando no `v` a esquerda da resposta :)

Answer (score 1):

Não funciona porque no caso do [`FlowLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html), não é bem desta forma que você configura o modo de alinhamento dele, não é como se faz com o `BorderLayout`.

Você deve recuperar o layout do JPanel e chamar o método [`setAlignment()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html#setAlignment(int)), passando um dos cinco modos suportados por esse gerenciador de layout, no seu caso, o modo [`FlowLayout.LEFT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html#LEFT):

```
painel = new JPanel();
FlowLayout layout = (FlowLayout) painel.getLayout();
layout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
painel.add(btn);
```

Ou simplificando:

```
((FlowLayout)painel.getLayout()).setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
```

Há outro jeito também, que é instanciando este layout na inicialização do painel, já passando o alinhamento, apesar de achar um desperdicio, pois este layout já é criado pelo java, mas pode ser uma opção:

```
painel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

---

Deixo aqui alguns links bastante úteis a respeito:

- [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
- [Using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)
- [How to Use Various Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html)